# javascript property accessors

Tags: javascript, accessor

In Javascript, it seems like using property accessors is not all that common (unlike in other OO languages such as Java for example).

If I have a `Person` object with a name, defined as

```
function Person(name) {
   this.name = name;
}
```

A person's name is not going to change, but I do want to be able to access it when needed, so I could do something like:

```
function Person(name) {
   var name = name;
   this.getName = function() {
      return name;
   }
}
```

Even in a dynamic language, I think the principles of using getters and setters apply the same way they do to statically typed OO languages (e.g. encapsulation, adding validation, restricting access, etc)

This question may get closed as subjective, but I'm curious as to why this behavior doesn't appear more often (e.g. Java developers would go crazy if everything was public).

Is there a "standard" way to do this in javascript? I've seen `Object.defineProperty`, but not all browsers support that.

Comment: I assume it might partially be related to the desire to reduce bandwidth loads. Extra markup means extra bits across the wire. While in the case of a small example like this, it might not seem relevant, in a robust application spanning tens of thousands of lines, it might become significant.

Comment: The extra definition also means extra memory usage on the client, along the same lines as my previous comment.

Comment: I think the answers already given show that this is not a good question for SO as it's prone to get opinion-based answers.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Javascript has intercept-able property accessors:

http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-getters-and-setters/

IMHO this is a far better solution to enforce the Uniform Access Principle than Java's more strict explicit getters, but that is also part of the simplicity and inflexibility of that language (Groovy for instance allows for similar interception).

Comment: in practice, is this seen a lot? Or typically do you see direct property access?

Comment: You'd use direct property access unless you need to modify the accessor logic: then you'd use the interception.  You may need to ask yourself _why_ you use getters and setters in Java if they don't do anything: what's the actual practical reason behind the encapsulation doctrine.

Comment: Sometimes I do ask myself the why, particularly on simple properties. Theoretically the idea is that if you wanted to add some other behavior in the getter or setter (e.g. logging, validation, etc). But in reality, that doesn't happen all that frequently on the simple properties, so it's more of a Java convention (I prefer how groovy does it where you don't explicitly declare the getters and setters but they are generated and automatically called, but allows you to write the syntax of straight property access).

Comment: Yes, maintainable changes in client code. In Java (and similar languages) using direct property access would complicate internal changes and also patterns like Decorator. Maybe not often needed, but the small investment could pay off big time. In languages that provide a more flexible way to hook into that (which includes most newer languages), logic can be applied when needed and left out when not (no pre-emptive convention necessary).

Answer (score 8):

I know my thoughts on the subject.

Getters and setters are evil.

Wait! Really! Bear with me a moment and let me explain.

Just using a method to get and set a value is .. well .. kinda pointless.  It doesn't protect, not really, and what you put in is what you get out.

On the other hand, I'm rather fond of methods that put information in, then get information back out.  BUT here is the magic part!  It isn't the same information.  Not directly.

```
function Person(name) {
  this.getFullName = function() {return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;};
  this.setBirthday = function(date) { this.birthday = date; };

  this.getAge = function() { /* Return age based on the birthday */ };
  this.isOfLegalDrinkingAge function() { /* do your math here too */ };
}
```

But most of the time I'm just shoving static data in and getting static data out.  What is the point of hiding it behind getters and setters?

As a secondary reason, dealing with the DOM and most host objects, you set properties.  You don't play with getters and setters.  Not using them fits the rest of the 'flavor' of what JS coders do.

Comment: @BillyMoon -- Wonders if he can change his username to "Javascript Preacher"

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I think the fact that it's not the javascript "flavor" is really what I was getting after here.

Comment: My problem with this is wondering whether things are functions or properties. Sometimes it can seem rather arbitrary. Person.firstName works, but Person.firstName() doesn't while on the contrary I need to use Person.fullName() instead of Person.fullName...

Comment: @CuddleBunny I understand what you mean.  You can always use the `typeof` operator and see if it is a function.  `console.log(typeof Person.firstName)`, for instance.

Comment: Sure, I can do that. I always use Visual Studio to develop in JS as well and it tends to tell me which it is. I just like consistency.

Answer (score 3):

I think the answer is that emulating classes in javascript is not the common practice, because the language is actually prototypal.

Although it is possible to create class like structures (as in your example), they are not really like java classes, and as a programmer, you end up fighting with the nuances.

If however, you embrace the prototypal nature of javascript, you are rewarded by a different, yet cohesive, and simple structure for the language.

It is not necessary to use getters and setters with prototypal structure, as you can simply set an object by, well, setting it to a value, and get it by, calling it as a value.

Javascript does not force you to write structured code, and does not stop you from doing so. I think the culture that has grown up around javascript has developed a good coding style, that is perfectly valid, and different from any other language I use.

I know this answer is not definitive, and conclusive, but hopefully there are some ideas in there that help you to find the anser you are looking for.

Comment: thanks. You could do the same get/set values directly in java (if you made things public for example), but that seems to be frowned upon. I guess a lot of it has to do with the what the idioms of the language have become.

Comment: A major issue in Java is that you don't want to have to change the interface of your class later. Being a compiled language designed for long-term code maintenance, priorities are different than for JS, a source-based language deployed in a rapidly-changing web environment.

Answer (score 0):

I apologize if I dont understand the question correctly, but self executing functions are one way to make members public/private

```
var Person = function(){
  var _name = "Roger",
      self = { getName : function (){ return _name; }};
  return self;
}()
```

You can then access Person.getName() from anywhere , but not set _name.

Comment: I know you are able to do this, it just seems like it's not really common practice...

Answer (score 0):

This is what I used for local fields:

```
TYPE_DEFAULT_VALUE= {
    number: 0,
    string: "",
    array: [],
    object: {},
};

typeOf = function (object) {
    if (typeof object === "number" && isNaN(object))
        return NaN;
    try {
        return Object.prototype.toString.call(object).slice(8, -1).toLowerCase();
    }
    catch(ex) {
        return "N/A";
    };
};

getAccessor = function(obj, key, type, defaultValue) {
    if (defaultValue === undefined) 
        defaultValue =  TYPE_DEFAULT_VALUE[type] === undefined ? null : TYPE_DEFAULT_VALUE[type];
    return {
        enumerable: true,
        configurable: true,
        get: function () {
            if (obj[key] === undefined) 
                obj[key] = defaultValue;
            return obj[key];
        },
        set: function (value) {
            if (typeOf(value) === type)
                obj[key] = value;
        },
    };
}

LocalFields = function (fields, object) {
    /**
    * field properties
    * { 
    *   type: [ required ] ( number | string | array | object | ... ),
    *   defaultValue: [ optional ]
    * }
    */
    if (! fields)
        throw "Too few parameters ...";
    if (! object) 
        object = this;

    var obj = this;
    var fieldsAccessor = {};
    for(key in fields){
        field = fields[key];
        fieldHandler = key[0].toUpperCase() + key.substr(1);
        if(! field.type)
            throw "Type not set for field: " + key;

        fieldsAccessor[fieldHandler] = getAccessor(obj, fieldHandler, field.type, field.defaultValue)
    }
    Object.defineProperties(object, fieldsAccessor);
}
```

Now for each Class I can just call something like:

```
Person = function(){
    new LocalFields({
        id:     { type: "number" },
        name:   { type: "string" },
    }, this);
}
```

And then like VS getter and setter you'll call:

```
var alex = new Person();
alex.Name = "Alex Ramsi";
console.clear();
console.info(alex.Name);
```