# Raise event whenever object property is added in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a Javascript  object :

`var obj={...};`

- How can I execute a function whenever a new property is added/changed :

  For example:`obj["newItem"]=3;`
- is there any way also for arrays ? (excpet override `push` in prototype)
- is there any way to do it also for assign a different object to the same variable ?

  example :

  ```
  var obj={...};
      obj={...}; //redifine
  ```

Comment: I don't believe there is, but I'd love to be proven wrong.

Comment: Yes you can, see [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy). What do you mean by "redefine an object"?

Comment: Maybe this question helps for the 1st problem.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12325791/javascript-property-accessors

Comment: [Object.watch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/watch)?

Comment: @Antony I believe watch is for modify and not for add....am I right ?

Comment: @RobW _assign a different object to the same variable_. I'll edit.

Comment: @RoyiNamir Do you want to override the object literal, ie. change the meaning of `{}`? Or do you want to magically update a variable without having a reference to the variable? Neither is possible.

Comment: @RobW No. I want to execute a function when an obj is referencing a new object. for example : if obj was referencing an object #1  , and then I do `obj=otherObject` so I changed the reference of which obj referes to. and hence i want to raise a function (if possible).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a proposal for something called [Object.observe](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony%3aobserve) that is meant exactly for this purpose. It's similar to [Object.watch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/watch) in Firefox.

There are also the [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) object that gives to you more flexibility.

However, neither of them are implement widely – you can use Proxy in case you're working on a Firefox add-on, for example.

Notice also that is true for the first points of your question but not to the last. Basically if you're doing:

```
var obj = {a: 1};

obj = {b: 1};
```

You're not "redefine" an object, the object itself is not touched, you just assign a different object to the same variable. If you want to monitoring the changes, that variable needs to be a properties of an object – for example, in the browsers any global variable is automatically property of the global object, in that case `window`, so you could do that.