# When to use accessor properties

Tags: javascript, oop

Normally, to access the properties of an object, change its value and receive the result I use this syntax.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var student={
      lastExam:null,
      setExam:function(es){
         this.lastExam=es
      },
     getExam:function(){return this.lastExam},
  } 
  student.setExam('Math')
  console.log(student.getExam())
</script>
```

To get the same result I could however use accessor properties with this code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var student={   
     lastExam:null,
     set Exam(es){
       this.lastExam=es
     },
     get Exam(){return this.lastExam},
   } 
  student.Exam='Math'
  console.log(student.Exam)
</script>
```

Although I've read some posts on this subject([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12325791/javascript-property-accessors/12325893#12325893),[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12325791/javascript-property-accessors/12325834#12325834) ecc..) I still don't understand some concepts.
My questions are: 
when it is more convenient to use a solution or other.
What are the implications of the use of these two solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first example can be executed in both ECMAScript 3 and 5, the second one only can be exectued in browsers that support ECMAScript 5.

Accesor properties are pretty fancy, and they work better in this kind of cases, but some users may not be able to run this code in their browsers.
The first example runs everywhere, although it's more tedious to use.

You'll hear out there that "accesor properties should only be used by people who makes libraries". Of course this is not true, and we all can use accesor properties, but there are some little compatibility issues with doing so.

Comment: :Thanks for your interest